# xpath to select tr that has several specific values in the columns

Tags: xpath

I have a table with multiple rows, and I'm trying to use an xpath to find the one row that contains specific values in each column. For example, I expect "foo" in column 1, "bar" in column 2, and "baz" in column 3.

What xpath could I use to get a row that contains those three specific values in those specific columns?

For example, given the following table I want to be able to get back only the one row with the three expected values in their expected columns

```
<table>
  <tr><td>foo</td><td>bar</td><td>xxx</td></tr>
  <tr><td>xxx</td><td>bar</td><td>baz</td></tr>
  <tr><td>foo</td><td>bar</td><td>baz</td></tr>
  <tr><td>bar</td><td>baz</td><td>foo</td></tr>
  <tr><td>foo</td><td>xxx</td><td>baz</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This does the trick (assuming the `table` element is the current context node):

```
    tr[(td[1] = 'foo') and (td[2] = 'bar') and (td[3] = 'baz')]
```

`td[1]` selects the first `td` child, `td[2]` the second, etc.  Then you combine the conditions with `and`.

Answer (score 1):

This also does the trick...I'm sure there are faster ways to get what you want though, by not using xpath..

//tr[td[1][text()='foo'] and td[2][text()='bar'] and td[3][text()='baz']]

Comment: There may be faster ways but a) I'm constrained to using selenium on IE, and b) none of my elements have distinguishing id, name or class attributes. It's a challenge :-\

Answer (score -1):

you can use `directorypath\[name="value"]\...` when searching

Comment: I know that, but how do I combine multiple conditions? I need "tr with column one with text of 'foo' and column two with text of 'bar'..."

Comment: so can you search within tr for "<td>foo</td><td>bar</td><td>baz</td>"?

Comment: I want to find any <tr> that specifically has "foo" in column 1, "bar" in column 2 and "baz" in column 3.

Comment: oh i see you  can use  tr[(td[1] ="name")]